# Utility Profiles --- ArcGIS

Tags: 3d, arcgis-platform, profile, arcgis-10.4, utility-network

I am currently working to convert our cities storm and sanitary sewers from 2D to 3D. Currently, we create profile views in CAD which means a lot of manual work anytime anything changes. We have a considerable number of manholes and mains mapped in GIS, and the ability to have dynamic data seems invaluable when it comes to profile work.

What I'm wondering is what the best way to go about this work is. I've been trying to use the point profile tool from the 3D analyst extension, but I'm unable to use it while showing our mains. I have downloaded the water utility network extensions, but I haven't been able to find any good documentation about how to actually use these or if I need to reformat all my existing data to use it.

I am lucky enough to have an enterprise license and should have access to any ESRI tool. We're running Arc 10.4. I know there's many different approaches so I'm very open to suggestions.

Comment: you can make sewer and storm profiles using the ArcGIS for Water Utilities add-in - we use it in the office.  I'll get the steps to do it once I get in the office and post back as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sewer and Storm Profiles can be created using the [ArcGIS for Water Utilities](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/) add-in [tools](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/tools/overview-reporting-tools/).

Your network data needs to be in a geometric network (so that it can trace from manhole to manhole).  There is a little [config](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/tools/configure-reporting-tools/#profiling) required to point the tool at the correct layers and elevation/ID/size fields in those layers (this is easier than the documentation makes it look - took me about 2 mins to modify just now).

To generate profiles you will need:

- Manhole data with Ground/Lid/Rim elevation and either Depth or Invert elevation
- Pipe data with Upstream and Downstream pipe elevation
- (Optional) Digital Terrain raster for ground levels to display in the background

Once you have this, you just click on the Profiling Tool,

[image]

click your two manholes, and the tool will trace between those manholes and generate your profile.

Here is the output from a quick sample from my Wastewater network.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! That is much more straight forward than the documentation.